# How to filter user without duplication that i have sent and received messages?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-filter

I want to create simple chat application between users.Here is part of the code:

Models.py:

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    message   = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    sender    = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="sent",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver  = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="received",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    read      = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Views.py:

```
def inbox(request):

    sent_list     = Chat.objects.filter(sender=request.user)
    received_list = Chat.objects.filter(receiver=request.user)
    inbox_list    = sent_list | received_list

    context={
    'inbox_list':inbox_list
    }

    return render(request,'blog/inbox.html',context)
```

Inbox.html:

```
{%for message in inbox_list %}
    {% if message.sender == request.user %}
      <a href="{% url 'chat' message.receiver.id %}" >{{message.receiver.username}}</a>
    {%else%}
      <a href="{% url 'chat' message.sender.id %}" >{{message.sender.username}}</a>
    {% endif%}
{% endfor%}
```

I get the chatters list in `Inbox.html` but for each message same users appear in list. How to filter the users only once that i have sent and received messages. Also if it is possible to create unique chat room,any recommendation would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have a basic alternative solution, I created a list for users, iterated all messages with for loop and for each message I added both message senders and receivers with if condition to prevent duplication.

Views.py:

```
def inbox(request):


sent=Chat.objects.filter(sender=request.user).distinct('receiver')
received=Chat.objects.filter(receiver=request.user).distinct('sender')
all= list(chain(sent, received))
users = []

for m in all:
    if not m.sender in users and not m.sender == request.user:
        users.append(m.sender)
    if not m.receiver in users and not m.receiver == request.user:
        users.append(m.receiver)

context={'users':users,}

return render(request,'blog/inbox.html',context)
```

Inbox.html:

```
<div class="container">
 {%for user in users %}
  <div>
   <img style="width:50px;height:50px;"class="profile-photo" src="    
    {{user.profile.image.url}}"/>
   <a href="{% url 'chat' user.username %}" >{{user.username}}</a>
  </div></br>
 {% endfor%}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Try using distinct() [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

Option 2: If you are trying to create data sets combining two models and if you need more control why not create a list/list-of-list as you need and render the same in template.

Comment: Even if i use `distinct()` at the end there is at least two duplicated object one of them in sent list another in received list. `sent=Chat.objects.filter(sender=request.user).distinct('receiver')
 received=Chat.objects.filter(receiver=request.user).distinct('sender')`